# VBA loop throught cells and extract the file name from cells in excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet that in each cell in column A , the path of a source folder :

```
         column A
P:\Desktop\Source\Test1-folder\file1.txt
P:\Desktop\Source\Test1-folder\file2.txt
```

and i want to take just the file name (file1.txt) for each file , how can i do it ? Can you help me please ?

```
 For Each oFolder In oSourceFolder.SubFolders
   lastcol = Cells(1, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
      If Dir(destinationFolder, 16) = "" Then MkDir (destinationFolder)
      For k = 1 To dercol
          numrows = worksh.Cells(Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Row
          For w = 2 To numrows
         filepath = worksh.Cells(w, icol).Value
```

But this one loops through the files, not the cells. How can I loop through the cells?

Comment: mid and instrrev should help, or you could split using formula MID & SUBSTITUTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
' Get the sheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

' How you will slash it
Dim strSlash As String
strSlash = "\"

' Set the range for your tool
Dim rngFiles As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngMaxRow As Long
lngMaxRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngFiles = Range("A1:A" & lngMaxRow)

' Grab it from the rear
For Each rngCell In rngFiles.Cells
    Debug.Print Right(rngCell.Value, Len(rngCell.Value) - InStrRev(rngCell.Value, strSlash))
Next
```

Comment: the line Len(rngCell.Value) - InStrRev(rngCell.Value, strSlash give me a 0 , it don t take the file name :s

Comment: Please post the value of the cell so I can see. Also, are your values using \ or / ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the file name, you can do this with a simple worksheet formula:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```